# JavaScript: Format number/currency w/regards to culture like .NET's String.Format()?

Tags: .net, javascript, internationalization, culture

This seems like a problem someone would've already solved in the year 2009, but I can't find a decent JavaScript library that will take a number like:

12345.58

And format it correctly based on a specific culture (ie, "nl-nl") or ISO currency code.

dojo showed promise, but it doesn't include many cultures by default, and actually wasn't working properly in my tests.

I basically want something that is 100% or near-100% equivalent to what .NET does for me, when I run:

String.Format([cultureInfo Object], "{0:N}", myValue) ' for numbers

and

String.Format([cultureInfo Object], "{0:C}", myValue) ' for currency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ASP.NET Ajax framework lets you do this.

Set the [EnableScriptGlobalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablescriptglobalization.aspx) property on the ScriptManager to true. You can then use the [Number.localeFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310813.aspx) function to format numbers.

Comment: Thanks, that is pointing me in the right direction. Know anything like that for currency, though? I guess I could try to roll my own, with Number.localeFormat formatting the number..

Comment: You should be able to just use "c", like `var currency = aNum.localeFormat("c");`

Comment: You can also specify the number of decimal digits. For example, "p4" will give you a percentage with 4 decimal places.