# Is there a functionality in JavaScript to convert values into specific locale formats?

Tags: javascript, numbers, currency

Is there a built in function of JavaScript to convert a string into a particular locale (Euro in my case)?

E.g. `50.00` should get converted to `50,00 €`.

Comment: 'Euro' is not a locale. A locale is e.g. German of Germany or de-DE (language tag as of [Ietf Bcp 47](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47)).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`50.00` is a unit-less value. The best you can do is convert `50.00` to `50,00` and then append the `€` yourself. Therefore, just use [`Number.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/ToLocaleString).

```
var i = 50.00;
alert(i.toLocaleString() + ' €'); // alerts '50.00 €' or '50,00 €'
```

[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/NcvbA/)

#### Lots of relevant questions:

- [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript) (the big one; ~70k views)
- [Convert to currency format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718878/javascript-convert-to-currency-format)
- [Format currency using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682789/format-currency-using-javascript)
- [how do i print currency format in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022171/how-do-i-print-currency-format-in-javascript)
- [JavaScript: Format number/currency w/regards to culture like .NET's String.Format()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615869/javascript-format-number-currency-w-regards-to-culture-like-nets-string-format) (possibly useful, if you're using ASP.NET)
- [format number to price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175720/format-number-to-price)

Comment: This does not work. After calling toFixed(2) a string is returned. So you're calling toLocaleString() on a string not an integer, which will not include changing '12.34' to '12,34' in French for instance.

Comment: The result of .toFixed() can be parsed back to a float, then it works, e.g. parseFloat((12.3456).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString()

Comment: @TvdH unfortunately that still doesn't work for `50`.

Comment: @Matt: You are right of course - since 50 and 50.00 is the same to JavaScript. This complicates matters, I came up with this:
`var number = 50, scale = 2;
console.log((((Math.round(number * Math.pow(10, scale)) * 10) + 1)
        / Math.pow(10, scale + 1))
    .toLocaleString()
    .slice(0, scale == 0 ? -2 : -1));`

Comment: This does not work out of the box - toFixed() return a string and toLocalString expects a number. Use: `price.toLocaleString(.culture, { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });`

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard That results in an _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."_ . I think it is the `.culture` part.

Answer (score 41):

I found a way to do this at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

You can you `toLocaleString` without using `toFixed` before it. `toFixed` returns a string, `toLocaleString` should get a number. But you can pass an options object with `toLocaleString`, the option `minimumFractionDigits` could help you with the functionality `toFixed` has.

```
50.toLocaleString('de-DE', {
    style: 'currency', 
    currency: 'EUR', 
    minimumFractionDigits: 2 
});
```

Checkout all the other options you can pass with this function.

Comment: Cool, but browser compatibility for options seems low though (IE 11 and Safari not supported)

Comment: As well as Firefox : Exception: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Comment: This should be the way to go. The comments above are outdated as ```options``` for ```toLocaleString``` does now work with all browsers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility). But you do not need to declare ```minimumFractionDigits``` seperately. It works fine just with ```style``` and ```currency```.

Comment: is there way to display "," instead of "."?

Answer (score 15):

There are locale related features described within the [ECMAScript Internationalization API](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/).

To get the float `50.0` converted to the string `50,00 €` (using the 'de-DE' locale) you need to write this:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE", {style: "currency", currency: "EUR"}).format(50.0)
```

This API is available in all current major browsers.

For more info about the number formatting features of the Internationalization API you should read the [article at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat).

Comment: This is a great solution now with modern JavaScript. Is there a reverse way to do it?

Answer (score 8):

I am working on an international site which deals with multiple currencies.

I didn't want to deal with setting the Locale every time I wanted to display a currency, so instead I made a prototype which formats the currency to the appropriate locale.  It is transparent in its conversions so you can customize it to your needs as well.

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(moneySymbol, decimalCharacter, thousandsCharacter, decimalPlaces, symbolLocation)
{
    var symbolLocation = (symbolLocation == undefined || symbolLocation < 1 || symbolLocation == "begin")?"begin":"end";
    var decimalPlaces = isNaN(decimalPlaces = Math.abs(decimalPlaces)) ? 2 : decimalPlaces;
    var thisNumber = parseFloat(this, decimalPlaces);
    var decimalCharacter = decimalCharacter == undefined ? "." : decimalCharacter;
    var thousandsCharacter = thousandsCharacter == undefined ? "," : thousandsCharacter;
    //var pm = thisNumber < 0 ? "-" : "";
    var pm = "";
    var pmB = thisNumber < 0 ? "(" : "";
    var pmE = thisNumber < 0 ? ")" : "";
    var i = parseInt(thisNumber = Math.abs(+thisNumber || 0)) + "";
    var j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    var retString = pmB;
    retString += ((symbolLocation == "begin")?((moneySymbol)?moneySymbol+"":""):"");
    retString += pm;
    retString += (j ? i.substr(0, j) + thousandsCharacter : "")
    retString += i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + thousandsCharacter);
    //alert((decimalPlaces ? decimalCharacter + (Math.ceil(Math.abs(thisNumber - i)*Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces))/Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces)).toFixed(decimalPlaces).slice(decimalPlaces) : "") + '\n' + Math.abs(thisNumber - i).toFixed(6));
    retString += (decimalPlaces ? decimalCharacter + (Math.ceil(Math.abs(thisNumber - i).toFixed(6)*Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces))/Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces)).toFixed(decimalPlaces).slice(decimalPlaces) : "");
    retString += ((symbolLocation == "end")?((moneySymbol)?moneySymbol+"":""):"");
    retString += pmE;
    return  retString;
};
Number.prototype.formatMoneyInternational = function(languageCode, inputCode)
{
    var languageCode = languageCode == undefined ? 'en_us' : languageCode;
    var inputCode = inputCode == undefined ? languageCode : inputCode;
    var currencies = {
        'float':    {'symbol':null,         'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':'.',  'comma': ''},       //Float
        //Arabic - Saudi Arabia ?(1025): Sorry, the server does not support this locale 
        //Arabic - Iraq ?(2049): Sorry, the server does not support this locale 
        //Arabic - Egypt ?(3073): Sorry, the server does not support this locale 
        //Arabic - Algeria ?(5121): Sorry, the server does not support this locale 
        'bg':       {'symbol':' BGN',       'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': ' '},      //Bulgarian 
        'ca':       {'symbol':' €',         'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Catalan 
        //Chinese - Traditional (1028): Sorry, the server does not support this locale 
        //Chinese - Simplified (2052): Sorry, the server does not support this locale 
        'cs':       {'symbol':' Kc',        'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': ' '},      //Czech 
        'da':       {'symbol':'kr ',        'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Danish 
        'de':       {'symbol':' €',         'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //German - Germany 
        'de_au':    {'symbol':' €',         'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //German - Austrian 
        'de_lu':    {'symbol':' €',         'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //German - Luxembourg 
        'el':       {'symbol':' €',         'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Greek 
        'en_us':    {'symbol':'$',          'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':'.',  'comma': ','},      //English - United States 
        'en_gb':    {'symbol':'£ ',         'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':'.',  'comma': ','},      //English - United Kingdom 
        'en_au':    {'symbol':'$ ',         'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':'.',  'comma': ','},      //English - Australia 
        'en_ca':    {'symbol':'$',          'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':'.',  'comma': ','},      //English - Canadian 
        'en_ie':    {'symbol':'€ ',         'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':'.',  'comma': ','},      //English - Irish 
        'es_mx':    {'symbol':'$ ',         'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':'.',  'comma': ','},      //Spanish - Mexico 
        'es':       {'symbol':' €',         'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Spanish - International 
        'fi':       {'symbol':' €',         'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': ' '},      //Finnish 
        'fr':       {'symbol':' €',         'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': ' '},      //French - France 
        'fr_ca':    {'symbol':' $',         'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': ' '},      //French - Canadian 
        'fr_ch':    {'symbol':'SFr. ',      'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':'.',  'comma': '\''}, //French - Swiss 
        //Hebrew ?(1037): Sorry, the server does not support this locale 
        'hu':       {'symbol':' Ft',        'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': ' '},      //Hungarian 
        'it':       {'symbol':'€ ',         'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Italian - Italy 
        'it_ch':    {'symbol':'&#8355; ',       'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':'.',  'comma': '\''}, //Italian - Swiss 
        'ja':       {'symbol':'¥ ',         'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':'.',  'comma': '\''}, //Japanese 
        //Korean (1042): Sorry, the server does not support this locale 
        'nl':       {'symbol':'€ ',         'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Dutch - Netherlands 
        'no':       {'symbol':'kr ',        'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':',',  'comma': ' '},      //Norwegian 
        'pl':       {'symbol':' zl',        'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': ' '},      //Polish 
        'pt_br':    {'symbol':'R$ ',        'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Portuguese - Brazil 
        'pt':       {'symbol':' €',         'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Portuguese - Standard 
        'ro':       {'symbol':' lei',       'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Romanian 
        'ru':       {'symbol':' p.',        'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': ' '},      //Russian 
        'hr':       {'symbol':' kn',        'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Croatian 
        'sr':       {'symbol':' Din.',      'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},          //Serbian - Latin 
        //'sr': {'symbol':' ???. ', 'symbolPosition': 'end',    'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},          //Serbian - Cyrillic 
        'sv':       {'symbol':' kr',        'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Swedish 
        //Thai (1054): Sorry, the server does not support this locale 
        'tr':       {'symbol':' TL',        'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Turkish 
        'id':       {'symbol':' Rp.',       'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':' ',  'comma': '.'},      //Indonesian 
        'uk':       {'symbol':' rpH.',      'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': ' '},          //Ukranian 
        'be':       {'symbol':' p.',        'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': ' '},      //Belausian 
        'sl':       {'symbol':' SIT',       'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},          //Slovenian 
        'et':       {'symbol':' kr',        'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':'.',  'comma': ' '},      //Estonian 
        'lv':       {'symbol':'Ls ',        'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':',',  'comma': ' '},      //Latvian 
        'lt':       {'symbol':' Lt',        'symbolPosition': 'end',        'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'},      //Lithuanian 
        //Farsi ?(1065): Sorry, the server does not support this locale 
        //Vietnamese (1066): Sorry, the server does not support this locale 
        'af':       {'symbol':'R ',         'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':'.',  'comma': ','},      //Afrikaans 
        'fo':       {'symbol':'kr ',        'symbolPosition': 'begin',      'decimal':',',  'comma': '.'}       //Faeroese
    };
    var currencyString = this+"";
    if(currencies[languageCode])
    {
        //alert(currencyString.replace(currencies[inputCode].comma, '').replace(currencies[inputCode].decimal, '.').replace(/[^\d\.\,\-]/g, ''));
        var currencyNumber = parseFloat(currencyString.replace(currencies[inputCode].comma, '').replace(currencies[inputCode].decimal, '.').replace(/[^\d\.\,\-]/g, ''));
        return currencyNumber.formatMoney(currencies[languageCode].symbol, currencies[languageCode].decimal, currencies[languageCode].comma, 2, currencies[languageCode].symbolPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        var currencyNumber = parseFloat(currencyString.replace(currencies['en_us'].decimal, '.').replace(currencies['en_us'].comma, '').replace(/[^\d\.\,\-]/g, ''));
        alert('Error: '  + languageCode + ' country code unknown.');
        return currencyNumber.formatMoney(currencies['en_us'].symbol, currencies['en_us'].decimal, currencies['en_us'].comma, 2, currencies['en_us'].symbolPosition);
    }
}
String.prototype.formatMoneyInternational = Number.prototype.formatMoneyInternational;
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer from Matt Ball is **wrong** - dunno why nobody haven't noticed. **There is no such function as `String.toLocaleString()` [[ref]](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)!** Therefore when `Number.toFixed()` returns String, the consequent `toLocaleString()` does nothing. So you won't get localized number, just the product of `toFixed()` function.

**WRONG (don't do it like this):**

```
var i = 1234.123;
alert(i.toFixed(2).toLocaleString() + ' €'); // ALWAYS alerts '1234.12 €' (no locale formatting)
```

**Suggestion how to do it right:**

You may use jQuery plugin like [NumberFormatter](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/).

Comment: So "how to **do** it"? in regular JS

Comment: Another reason not to use W3Schools as a reference.

Answer (score 4):

Built-in, yes and no. There is `Number.toLocaleString()` but it is dependent on the system's locale.

However, there are some libraries which have modules for this. [MooTools](http://mootools.net)'s [Locale.Number](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Locale/Number) for example allows you to convert a number into different locales (adding your own locale is trivial).

```
Locale.use("EU");
var inEuros = (50).formatCurrency(); // € 50,00
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N3AqM/)

---

If you want the € sign to be printed after, you can simply create your own locale:

```
Locale.define('EU-suffix', 'Number', {
    currency: {
        suffix: ' €'
    }
}).inherit('EU', 'Number');
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers are okay but I would recommend a different library, [NumeralJS](http://numeraljs.com/) over Number.toLocaleString because the latter is not supported widely in all browsers (it breaks on even new versions of safari).  NumeralJS is really powerful and supports anything you would want to do with converting numbers to strings.

First, set the language (I chose french) and then format it:

```
numeral.language('fr');
numeral(50.00).format('0.00 $');
```

Outputs:

```
"50,00 €"
```

The website explains it quite well and has tons of examples.

Answer (score 0):

For javascript use the accounting library http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/ Then you can do:

```
// Default usage:
accounting.formatMoney(12345678); // $12,345,678.00

// European formatting (custom symbol and separators), can also use     options object as second parameter:
accounting.formatMoney(4999.99, "€", 2, ".", ","); // €4.999,99

// Negative values can be formatted nicely:
accounting.formatMoney(-500000, "£ ", 0); // £ -500,000

// Simple `format` string allows control of symbol position (%v = value, %s = symbol):
accounting.formatMoney(5318008, { symbol: "GBP",  format: "%v %s" }); // 5,318,008.00 GBP
```