# How to format number to a currency format using String.localeFormat() using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Number `56675.456`

I want to format this number with Format : `{0:$###.##}`

using `String.localeFormat()` in JQuery

Expected Result: `$56675.46`

Comment: `String.localeFormat()` is not a jQuery / JavaScript function (i think its .Net)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - convert to European locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314237/javascript-convert-to-european-locale) <- there are some great answers to this question - a starting point at least

Comment: You're probably thinking of the _JavaScript_ `Number.toLocaleString()` function (see the question ManseUK linked to). jQuery doesn't have any number formatting methods (that I know of).

Answer (score 1):

```
function convert(num) {    
  return "$" + (num.toFixed(2));
}

convert(56675.456)
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gvst/1/)